# Passing Values between scripts in Unity 2020.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the value ballVelocity in class Ball to be read in class GameStatus.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
public float ballVelocityY;
Rigidbody2D ridgidBody2D;
void Start()
    {
        ridgidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ballVelocityY = System.Math.Abs(ridgidBody2D.velocity.y);
    }
void Update()
    {
        ballVelocityY = System.Math.Abs(ridgidBody2D.velocity.y);
    }
    public float GetBallVelocityY()
    {
        return ballVelocityY;
    }
}
public class GameStatus : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float ballVelocity = 0f;

    // states
    [SerializeField] public int currentScore = 0;
    Ball ball;
 void Start()
    {
        ball = GetComponent<Ball>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        ballVelocity = ball.GetBallVelocityY();
    }
}
```

I've tried everything in [this](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-get-a-variable-from-another-script-in-unity-the-right-way/) place. None of them seem to work. (Yes, I tried just calling the variable directly.)

Comment: Is Ball script attached to the same GameObject as GameStatus script? Because with the code you wrote this is what you are assuming. And what does it mean "none seems to work?". What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I've also tried, ```ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y```
And ```GetComponent<Ball>().GetComponent<RidgidBody2D>().velocity.y```

Comment: Yes. They are both part of the same "scene/level". and are both children of the same level.

Comment: What is Scene/Level in your context?

Comment: `They are both part of the same "scene/level". and are both children of the same level` .. how about reading the API? `GetComponent` only looks for the component on the very same GameObject ... if it is somewhere in the same object hierarchy use `GetComponentInChildren` or `GetComponentInParent` .. otherwise use `FindObjectOfType` ...

Comment: derHugo. I am not really sure why, but reading technical documentation doesn't work for me. No idea why, but I almost never understand what it's saying. I am a Electronics Tech who can repair extremely complex systems with almost no effort. But, reading the books just confuses me. No idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use:

```
GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Ball>();
```

instead of

```
GetComponent<Ball>();
```

Provided that there is only one Ball in your scene. (GetComponent only looks for a component on the same game object.)

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem nicely. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TomareUtsuZo - if you're happy that an answer solves your problem, accept it (by clicking the grey tick on the left). Don't edit the question to put "solved" in the title.

Comment: Wai Ha Lee. Thank you. That helps a lot.